# Cross thread operation not valid:

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a user control which contain only a ZedGraph.

I trying to write a method for this user control called additself which will add itself to a tab page of the main form.

```
TabPage newpage = new TabPage();
newpage.Controls.Add(this.zedGraphControl1);
(form1.Controls["tableLayoutPanel1"].Controls["tabControl1"] as TabControl).TabPages.Add(newpage);
```

As it is a cross thread operation, there will be an error and I fix it by adding

```
TabPage newpage = new TabPage();
newpage.Controls.Add(this.zedGraphControl1);
form1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
    (form1.Controls["tableLayoutPanel1"].Controls["tabControl1"] as TabControl).TabPages.Add(newpage);
});
```

For some reason, it still give a error message saying zedgraph was accessed from the thread it is created on.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Does adding a new tabpage really take so much time you need to do it on a background thread? In any case, wouldn't this make the tabpage be owned by your thread, the the tab control be owned by the foreground thread?

Comment: Probably because you created the TabPage in the wrong thread, put it inside the delegate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are still creating the control on a different thread; you only put the code to insert it into your form onto the UI thread. Move everything starting with `TabPage newpage = new TabPage();` into `Invoke()`.